# Which NB is used in glm.nb in R?

Tags: r, regression

Accordingly to J.M Hilbe, Negative Binomial Regression, there exists about 25 different types of Negative Binomial regressions where the method known as NB-2 is used the most. Which begs the question - which NB-regression method do R use when applying glm.nb()?

Comment: I don't know, but assuming you're talking about the `glm.nb` function in the package **MASS**, you have access to the source code. You can read it and find out for yourself.

Comment: I found the MASS source code at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html - look in the file named neg.bin.R